# Can't change focus after first "focus" call

Tags: tcl

In TCL i find i can't change focus after the first `focus` call

Here is a MRE:

```
frame .f -padx 15 -pady 15

spinbox .f.spin1 -from 0 -to 10 -width 5 -relief solid -highlightthickness 1 -highlightcolor blue -borderwidth 1 -textvariable ::a
spinbox .f.spin2 -from 0 -to 10  -width 5 -relief solid -highlightthickness 1 -highlightcolor blue -borderwidth 1 -textvariable ::b
spinbox .f.spin3 -from 0 -to 10 -width 5 -relief solid -highlightthickness 1 -highlightcolor blue -borderwidth 1 -textvariable ::c

# note that changing the focus in the bindings works as expected
bind .f.spin1 <Key> { if {"%K" eq "Left"} { focus .f.spin3 } }
bind .f.spin1 <Key> {+ if {"%K" eq "Right"} { focus .f.spin2 } }

bind .f.spin2 <Key> { if {"%K" eq "Left"} { focus .f.spin1 } }
bind .f.spin2 <Key> {+ if {"%K" eq "Right"} { focus .f.spin3 } }

bind .f.spin3 <Key> { if {"%K" eq "Left"} { focus .f.spin2 } }
bind .f.spin3 <Key> {+ if {"%K" eq "Right"} { focus .f.spin1 } }

pack .f
grid .f.spin1 -column 1 -row 0
grid .f.spin2 -column 2 -row 0
grid .f.spin3 -column 3 -row 0

# with no focus invocation, no spinbox will be focused when the window opens
# we'll call focus on spin2 as default

# this works as expected
focus -force .f.spin2

# if some condition is met we want to change the focus to spin3
# but the following invocation doesn't change the focus
if { 1 } {
    focus -force .f.spin3
}
```

I've also tried (with no success) focusing on the frame before spin3

```
focus -force .f.spin2
focus -force .f
focus -force .f.spin3
```

I did try (again with no success) using `after idle`

```
after idle { focus -force .f.spin3 }
```

What did work was using `after 1000` but it is not elegant in terms of code. And also not good to the user as (s)he might type before the focus change. I've tried smaller values but focus wouldn't change for small values so this is not a dependable solution.

Why is this happen? How can i fix it?

edit: (not sure if relevant but i'm on Win10)

Answer (score 1):

This bug appears on Linux also.
I opened up a [ticket](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/tktview/08e2f8e6f05f0752648be67fc7645bb51722ab6a) for this.

Workaround 1:

```
update
focus -force .f.spin3
```

Workaround 2:

```
after 100 [list focus -force .f.spin3]
```